# Is there a way to dynamically grab an HTML page from Browser.OpenAsync?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm working on creating an Android application that makes scheduling jobs easier, and I don't have access to the database that holds the shifts. The user logs into the website (which uses Single Sign On) and authenticates the users is using a browser. Because of this, I can't write GET and POST commands to grab the information I need; I believe I have to create a web **scraper**.

What I currently have implemented is using Browser.OpenAsync() to open up the default browser and sign in like one normally would. My problem is that I need to grab the HTML from the page that opens up after login, and I haven't found any documentation to be able to do so. This is what I currently have

C#

```
 public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
            

        }

        [Java.Interop.Export("ButtonClick")]
        public void SignIn(View v)
        {
            ConnectToWebAsync(username, password);           

        }

        public async Task ConnectToWebAsync(string username, string password)
        {
            Browser.OpenAsync("https://example.com/", BrowserLaunchMode.SystemPreferred);
        }


    public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Use the WebView control instead of opening an external browser. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview?tabs=windows

Comment: do you mean you want to get the codes of html which you open ?

Comment: I've tried the WebView implementation, but it seems to crash after I login. It says it is loading, but nothing happens.

Comment: is there any error message when you crash with webview ?you could show it,it's helpful for finding out the issue